# Can I take a screenshot tough shh connection and open it on other mac?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

(Sorry for my bad english)

Ok so i'm connecting from a mac book pro to a stationary mac trough ssh in the Mac Terminal, and I'm wondering if there's any way I can take a screenshot of the mac i'm connecting to and show it on the mac i'm connections from.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : This not exactly what’s the OP asked for, but it’s probably close to what he needs.

You should open a ssh tunnel and connect via the built in VNC server.

See ssh tunnel [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh).

See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16976/whats-a-good-ssh-tunneling-client-for-os-x